# Setup MongoDB cluster on windows 7 for Learning purpose

Tags: mongodb

I am learning MongoDB on Windows 7 machine with 4GB ram.
I installed MongoDB 3.2.Not possible to install vmware on my machine.
I would like to practice Cluster configuration/Sharding/Replication/mongodb ops center.

Is it possible to do on single windows machine.

Please share your suggestions.

Thanks & Regards,

Answer (score 0):

try using containers like docker, it is lighter than virtual machine and will also add to your knowledge for knowing how to work with docker.

good luck.